# Disable CASCADE DELETE on a property to avoid different cascading paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent

I'm developing a library with Entity Framework 6.1.0 Code First, .NET Framework 4.5, C# and SQL Server.

I have these two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User Sender { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

And these configurations file:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("User");

        Property(u => u.UserName).IsRequired();
        Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(50);

        HasMany(u => u.Groups).
            WithMany(g => g.Members).
                Map(ug =>
                {
                    ug.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                    ug.MapRightKey("GroupId");
                    ug.ToTable("UserGroup");
                });
    }
}

public class MessageConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Message>
{
    public MessageConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Message");

        Property(m => m.Body).IsRequired();
        Property(m => m.Body).IsMaxLength();

        Property(m => m.DateSent).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(m => m.Sender).
            WithMany(u => u.MessagesSent).
            HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);

        HasMany(r => r.Recipients).
            WithMany(m => m.MessagesReceived).
            Map(mr =>
            {
                mr.ToTable("MessageRecipient");
                mr.MapLeftKey("MessageId");
                mr.MapRightKey("UserId");
            });
    }
}
```

The first time I run this project I get the following message:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.MessageRecipient_dbo.User_UserId' on table
'MessageRecipient' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION
or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Users won't be deleted from my database, but I don't know how to fix this problem.

I think the problem is that a message has a sender (an `user`) and also has one or more recipients (`user`). This creates different cascade paths (which is not allowed with SQL Server).

How can I disable those cascade paths? Maybe on `Message.Sender`.

Comment: Could you include the Group class and its configuration? I added a group based on this code but could not reproduce this error.

Comment: @MárkGergelyDolinka I'm sorry, but I don't have any problem between Group and Message. I have update my question removing any references to group and I having the same error.

Comment: Thanks, I asked about the Groups because both the Message and the User entity had relationship with them. Now I tried this new code, I don't get an error when creating the database with Migrations, do you use migrations or initializers?

Other thing: when deleting a user who has both received and sent messages I get the error: {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.Messages_dbo.Users_User_UserId\". The conflict occurred in database \"EF61OnDeleteNoAction\", table \"dbo.Messages\", column 'User_UserId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: No, I'm creating the database and I'm not using migrations. This afternoon I'll give you more details.

Comment: @MárkGergelyDolinka Which database are you using? I'm using SQL Server and it doesn't allow multiple cascade paths.

Comment: @MárkGergelyDolinka I have found the problem. See my answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

Before I had on `MessageConfiguration`:

```
HasRequired(m => m.Sender).
    WithMany(u => u.MessagesSent).
    HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);
```

Now I have:

```
HasRequired(m => m.Sender).
    WithMany(u => u.MessagesSent).
    HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId).
    WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The problem is that SQL Server doesn't allow multiple cascade paths. If you delete an user you could have two delete cascade on `Message`: one on `Message.Sender` and another one on `Message.Recipients`.